# Exception Plugin class doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, exception

I try to create a plugin and getting following error

[image: plugin does not exist error]

**Loginpost/Redirect/frontend/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="loginpost_redirect_loginpostplugin" type="\LoginPost\Redirect\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

**Loginpost/Redirect/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Loginpost\Redirect\Plugin;

class LoginPostPlugin
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('/checkout');
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: i think issue of namespace.... in your path vendor name is "Loginpost" and define in di.xml "LoginPost"

Answer (score 1):

**I think Issue Is In Your Name Space..**

In your Path module name is **Loginpost** and define in `di.xml` **LoginPost**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="loginpost_redirect_loginpostplugin" type="\Loginpost\Redirect\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code in di.xml with following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
      <plugin name="loginpost_redirect_loginpostplugin" type="LoginPost\Redirect\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
   </type>
</config>
```